# how can i set return so it accepts class1 or class2?

Tags: c#, class

how can i, in my function start to fill the parameters for the class it is supposed to return, but if an exception occurs i'll return my error class instead?

```
public **** function()
    {
        try
        {
            Articles articles = new Articles();
            articles.articleid = 234;
            articles.articlename = "Milk";
            articles.deleted = 0;

            //continue fill Articles 
            //and an exception occurs


            return articles;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Errors Error = new Errors();
            Error.exceptionmessage = e.Message;
            Error.exceptionname = e.ToString();
            Error.httpcode = 500;


            return Error;
        }
    }
```

is this possible and a good thing to do? or should i just extend all return classes with my error class, even though i will return much info with allot of null values.
i would like to send as little data as possible and if my function fails i'll just send back the error.

UPDATE

sorry for not giving enough inforamtion about my situation this is a function that i want to use in a webservice

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    **** Function();
```

so i dont think i can just throw an exception. i would like to return a class of articles if all is well so i dont have to convert my data to JSON but if something goes wrong i would like to send http code 500 Internal Server Error to the client. 
i have not yet read all answers but i think i'll have to include my error class in all my other return classes so the client can now when something went wrong?

Comment: You just don't, really, in this kind of scenario.

Comment: Instead of returning an error, why don't you throw an exception? If the situation doesn't warrant an exception, then create a new class to encapsulate the return type or an error.

Comment: Why not re-throw said error and let your upper function catch it.

Comment: Don't, don't, don't. This is what exceptions are for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return one of two possible objects of different types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491062/return-one-of-two-possible-objects-of-different-types)

Comment: You got to work more on the question, all the aswers which are given are reasonable

Comment: @Dendei oh so its for consuming WCF in javascript. please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would honestly advise against doing what you suggest. Instead, either use an existing `Exception` type or create a new subclass of `Exception` and throw it. You can even retain the causing exception information in the new exception's `InnerException` if so desired.

---

If the situation does not warrant an exception, however (you have not given enough details about what you are doing), you can create a `Result` class that contains error/warning information. This kind of thing would be better suited for warnings, though. That is, it is not an error condition that prevents things from continuing (exception), but instead a message that the calling code could choose to ignore without drastic side-effects.

For example:

```
class Result<T>
{
    public Result(T Value, Errors Errors = null)
    {
        this.Value = Value;
        this.Errors = Errors;
    }

    public T Value {get; private set;}

    public Errors Errors {get; private set;}
}
```

Usage (as per your example code):

```
public Result<Articles> function()
{
    try
    {
        Articles articles = new Articles();
        articles.articleid = 234;
        articles.articlename = "Milk";
        articles.deleted = 0;

        //continue fill Articles 
        //and an exception occurs


        return new Result(articles);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Errors Error = new Errors();
        Error.exceptionmessage = e.Message;
        Error.exceptionname = e.ToString();
        Error.httpcode = 500;


        return new Result<Articles>(null, Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this is my best option thank you i will try this out.

Comment: this worked very fine :) thank you if i get an exception now i dont have to send the whole structure of null values in articles just the error.

Comment: when i display the results now i see Errors=null and Value holds my article info. do you know a way to make value display as articles?

Comment: yes but when i display the results i would like value to be named "articles"

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE:

That gives more insight on what you want to do. Since you can't throw exceptions, you should have a base result class. I usually do this for WCF methods I call through javascript, since it can't handle the exceptions nicely.

So you'll want a base class like:

```
[DataContract]
public class AjaxResult
{
    public static AjaxResult GetSuccessResult()
    {
        return new AjaxResult();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can inherit this, adding any data you would want to return. This example returns a single product object and a list of validation errors.

```
[DataContract]
public class SingleProductResult : AjaxResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public Product Data { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IList<int> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}
```

You can also opt to create a generic wrapper so you don't have to write to much code in your methods. I usually put this in a base class and let all WCF services inherit from that class.

```
protected T PerformAjaxOperation<T>(Func<T> action) where T : AjaxResult, new()
{
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    catch (AccessDeniedException ade)
    {
        // -- user tried to perform an invalid action
        return new T()
        {
            Status = AjaxErrorCodes.AccessDenied,
            Error = ade.ToString()
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new T()
        {
            Error = ex.ToString(),
            Status = 1
        };
    }
}
```

Then just use it like so:

```
public SingleProductResult GetProduct(int productId)
{
    return PerformAjaxOperation(() =>
    {
        return retval = new SingleProductResult()
            {
                Data = ProductServiceInstance.GetProduct(productId)
            };
    });
}
public AjaxResult DeleteProduct(int productId)
{
    return PerformAjaxOperation(() => {
        ProductServiceInstance.DeleteProduct(productId);
        return AjaxResult.GetSuccessResult();
    });
}
```

So, if everything proceeds smoothly, error will be 0 and message will be null. If an exception is thrown, then it will be caught by the `PerformAjaxOperation()` function and stuffed inside the `AjaxResult` object (or a derivative of it) and return to the client.

---

**Previous answer:**

I don't think this is a good idea. What you can do is create a custom exception by creating a class that inherits from `Exception` and add properties there that you want to save. Then when an exception occurs, you just catch it and stuff it inside this new exception along with other details. Then throw this exception instead. You can then catch this exception in the higher levels and display the proper message.

an example:

```
public IList<Articles> GetArticles()
{
    try
    {
        return GetSomeArticlesFromDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception innerException)
    {
        throw new MyCustomException("some data", 500, innerException);
    }
}
public class MyCustomException : Exception
{
    public int HttpCode { get; set; }
    public MyCustomException(string errorMessage, int httpCode, Exception innerException)
        : base(errorMessage, innerException) {
            HttpCode = httpCode;
    }
}
public void EntryPoint()
{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
        var result = GetArticles();
        DoSomething();
        DisplayResult(result);
    }
    catch (MyCustomException ex)
    {
        ReturnHttpError(ex.Message, ex.HttpCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats the stuff !!! correct and standardized.
started to write the same thing untill i noticed :)

Answer (score 1):

If `class1` and `class2` have a common base type or common interface, use that. But in this case, you could create a wrapper class to encapsulate both result types, like this:

```
class MethodResult<T>
{
    public T Result { get; private set; }
    public Errors Errors { get; private set; }

    public MethodResult(T result) { this.Result = result; }
    public MethodResult(Errors errors) { this.Errors = errors; }
}

public MethodResult<Articles> MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        ... 
        return new MethodResult<Articles>(articles);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        ... 
        return new MethodResult<Articles>(errors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In light of additional information in the question, since this is a WCF service, you could throw a [`WebFaultException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webfaultexception.aspx):

```
public Articles function()
{
    try
    {
        Articles articles = new Articles();
        articles.articleid = 234;
        articles.articlename = "Milk";
        articles.deleted = 0;

        //continue fill Articles 
        //and an exception occurs


        return articles;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new WebFaultException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Message = e.Message
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh maybe that is even better sorry for not including all information. your latest answer got me what i wanted though but this is probably what i need.

Comment: can i make an custom faultexception with the same information since i would like to keep to .net 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `out` keyword,

```
public Articles function(out Error err)
    {
        Articles articles = null;
        err = null;
        try
        {
            articles = new Articles();
            articles.articleid = 234;
            articles.articlename = "Milk";
            articles.deleted = 0;
            // Set your article values

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Errors ex = new Errors();
            ex.exceptionmessage = e.Message;
            ex.exceptionname = e.ToString();
            ex.httpcode = 500;

            err = ex;
        }
        return articles;
    }
```

Comment: this won't compile because not all paths return a value or populate the out parameter.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Throw exceptions, don't pass the around

Answer (score 0):

The ways that other answers have handled this involve technical methods of how to define the two classes, using interfaces and subclassing.

However, fundamentally you're actually solving the wrong problem. You will still need to write code in the caller that distinguishes between the two types of object, as well as documenting the way in which your function works.

Personally, I would create a new Exception class for the type of error you may be handling, and throw that instead, for example:

```
public class InvalidArticleException: Exception {
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionName { get; set; }
    public int HttpCode { get; set; }

}

public **** function()
{
    try
    {
        // DO STUFF
        return articles;
    }
    catch (InvalidArgumentException e)
    {
        throw new InvalidArticleException() {
            ExceptionMessage = e.Message,
            ExceptionName = e.ToString(),
            HttpCode = 500
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {   // Not actually required; left in for future debugging
       throw ex;             
    }
}
```

Callers would then be able to catch the exception and examine it for the error details, with code that is kept separated from that which processes the returned articles.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why would you want swallowing the exeptions, but if you do whatn this behgaviour make a return type common for both type. The both classes inherit from object so you can change the method signature to `public object function()`