# Call a common function from a list of objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a Proxy Scraper. For each website I have, I try to scrape the proxies. The scrape code for each website is in a class with the name of the website.

For example:

I have the websites "wwww.proxy.com and www.moreproxy.com"

I have 2 classes: Proxy and MoreProxy with the functions "scrape" that varies for both (since they are different websites).

To get the lists, I do something like this:

```
//The below code doesn't exist, but just to get my point across
//Each datagrid.Add is in a separate thread
datagrid.Add(new Proxy().scrape());
datagrid.Add(new MoreProxy().scrape());
datagrid.Add(...);
datagrid.Add(...);
//And so on for all the other websites I might add...
```

Now is there a way to loop this? I was trying something like this, but it does not work:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>();
objects.Add(new Proxy(), new MoreProxy(), ..., ...); //I can update this each time I add a new website

foreach(object o in objects)
{
    datagrid.Add(o.scrape());
}
```

The scrape function looks something like this:

```
public List<string[]> scrape()
{
        HtmlDocument PageContent = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://free-proxy-list.net/");
        HtmlNode[] nodes = PageContent.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td").ToArray();

        List<string[]> proxies = new List<string[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i += 8)
        {
            string[] proxy = { nodes[i].InnerHtml, nodes[i + 1].InnerHtml };
            proxies.Add(proxy);
        }

        return proxies;
}
```

Does something like this exist? Basically I have several classes with a common function scrape. I want to create a list of all these classes as objects, and execute the function scrape. How would I do that (solution needs to be thread safe)

Comment: You can use an interface or an base class that both will implement, then you should be able to do this. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491062/return-one-of-two-possible-objects-of-different-types-sharing-a-method, saying that, your list will contain a list of the base class/interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup an interface:

```
public interface IScrape()
{
   object Scrape();
}
```

Have your proxy classes implement the interface:

```
// repeat for Proxy
public class MyProxy : IScrape{
  object Scrape()
  {
     return something;
  }
}
```

then

```
List<IScrape> objects = new List<IScrape>();
objects.Add(new Proxy(), new MoreProxy(), ..., ...); //I can update this each time I add a new website

foreach(IScrape o in objects)
{
    datagrid.Add(o.Scrape());
}
```

Comment: Will this work if each object is running simultaneously in different threads?

Comment: The specifics of the code listing you provided did not imply anything to do with thread safety. If the code inside `Scrape()` is thread-safe, then yes, the operation is thread-safe. If the code inside `Scrape()` (each implementation of it!) is not thread-safe, then no, operation is not thread safe.

Comment: What can I do inside `object Scrape() { }` to make it thread safe?

Comment: I showed my scrape function now.

Comment: where does `AllScrapedElements` come from? this is something that would make it non-threadsafe.

Comment: It comes from scraping the HTML page... I edited the function so you can see where it comes from.

Comment: With the adjusted listing, it probably is thread-safe, depends on how this code `Html.load("http://proxy.com").AllElementsThatStartWith("a href=")` is written :) To make something thread-safe you need to ensure that either: a) all the variables in the methods are on the stack of the methods or b) that you implement a synchronization mechanism e.g. `lock` or `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to ensure that no one thread con modify variable state leaving the other thread inconsistent.

Comment: Okay I edited the scrape function to be one of the actual scrape functions from my program. I think its thread safe according to what you have said. Would you agree?

Comment: Nevermind - it was thread safe - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are the problems solution.

Like this:

```
public interface IScrapable {
    void Scrape();
}

public class Proxy : IScrapeable {
    public void Scrape() { ...}
}
```

Now you can Loop and scrape your objects.

```
 List<IScrapable> objects = new List<IScrapable>();
objects.Add(new Proxy(), new MoreProxy(), ..., ...); //I can update this each time I add a new website

foreach(IScrapable o in objects)
{
    datagrid.Add(o.scrape());
}
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Is this thread safe, and if not, how would I make it thread safe? Would a locker object work?

Comment: The only thing which could possibly be not Threadsafe is the method `scrape()` but you didnt showed us what you do in your method, so we can't tell you if you're code is Threadsafe or not

Comment: To make the Method thread-safe you could lock it... `public void scrape() { lock(SomeObjectUsedForLocking) { ... }}` [Link to MSDN-Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

Comment: Hi, I showed my scrape function now.